Uniform convergence impies pointwise convergence. Am I missing something?
I'm reading 'Calculus 3rd Ed.' by M. Spivak, specifically a Corollary in Chapter 24. In it, the following is stated:

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.
(1) If each $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
(2) If $f$ and each $f_n$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then
$$\int_a^b f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_a^b f_n$$
Moreover, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges (pointwise) to $f$ on $[a,b]$, each $f_n$ has an integrable derivative $f_n'$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to some continuous function, then
(3) $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'_n(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

My question is that, why did the author write "Moreover, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges (pointwise)..." when we already assumed it converged uniformly? I'm almost certain this is just an oversight but wanted to ask on here in order to be 100% sure I wasn't missing some basic fact about pointwise convergence breaking down when it comes to sums of functions (as I have done before).

It’s a different theorem all together, so they’re different $f_n$’s and $f$’s.

Yeah, sloppy writing. Should have broken that out into a separate theorem or not reused the names $f_n,f.$ Should have used $g_n,g$ or something else.

You might consider the word "Moreover" here to be "As a corollary, ..." (if this new result follows from the first part.)

@ThomasAndrews, thank you! I'm glad to hear I'm not losing it

Yeah, this is one of those cases where you figure out what is meant by first reading what is actually written, realize it doesn't make sense (in this case to assume pointwise convergence when we've already assumed uniform convergence,) and then hope the author meant this other thing.
